# is it better to have several google sheets for google forms answers vs only one sheet receiving all answers?

Tags: performance, google-sheets, google-forms, gs-vlookup, importrange

not a problem but a question

I was wondering for google sheets and google forms, what is the best practice and performance?

I have a little project consisting in several google forms, they give the answers in several tabs in one master sheet, and I have a lot of calculations, importranges, arrayformulas, vlookups, time calculations, etc. Like a little ERP, kpis, cmr, etc. then I import my erp database, do calculations, then I show the results via `IMPORTRANGE`S

so far it works ok, kinda fast, when I copy paste the db from my erp, it takes like 15 secs to do the maths. but I wonder if I had all the answers in separate sheets, it would be faster? it would be better for the importrange vlookups? it would be the same?

so far my importranges works fine, but I fear they would be bad for using vlookups in external sheets

Answer (score 1):

too much `IMPORTRANGE`s will slow down your sheet as well. best practice would be have those forms to output all stuff in one spreadsheet, then do the hard math avoiding per cell formulas or unnecessary heavy formulas (`QUERY`, `VLOOKUP`, etc.) if possible and have all in ArrayFormulas. then when done export the final result via `IMPORTRANGE` and "forever" close that form/calculation sheet

Comment: THANKS, yes, that is what i do now, but i always wonder about having the forms output to external sheets and using vlookups + importranges